# Speed of physics simulation

Tags: animation, physics

Can I slow down the speed at which things happen, without lowering the frame rate?
I want to make [this](https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B8DSswciTQalZVBMTjh3YVhKSG8/view?usp=drivesdk) happen slowly without decreasing the fps.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can set the speed of the physics simulation by simply changing the Speed setting in the Rigid Body World settings in the Scene tab :

[image: rigid world speed]

Smaller values will reduce the speed (ie, 0.5 will slow it down to half-speed).

Comment: And to add to that, essentially if your animation is 24 frames per second. At half speed, your simulation will run at 48 frames per second.

Comment: @LetTheWritersWrite yup that's just logic, but when I will make the animation, I'll decrease the fps while rendering the video to get the desired fps.